# Router reports really low line attenuation, what could be the cause?

Tags: networking, router, modem, adsl

[image]

I remember reading that below 5 for line attenuation is danger zone level bad. This is a new phone line, new dsl, so i havent yet tested it fully with torrenting, etc.

Comment: Doesn't attenuation roughly translate to "loss of power/signal"? Low attenuation would be a _good_ thing. You might be mixing it up with signal/noise ratio...

Answer (score 0):

If you are very close to the telephone exchange and have a *new* line (as in a new cable), that would explain the low attenuation.

Attenuation describes the "loss of signal", so in general less is better. [This](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/what-is-considered-good-dsl-line-attenuation-371) resource actually seems to support that statement. I wouldn't worry about it unless you run into issues. If the signal is too strong, it might cause issues with some modems (although I have seen this on cable/DOCSIS, I've never seen it on DSL).

If you actually run into problems, call your ISP/Telco and they can put an attenuator box in.